# Are there any cms/social networking platforms that facilitate the creation of multiple communities?

Tags: content-management-system, social-networking

We are building an app that we want to add social networking like features too.  Our first thought was to take an open source social networking platform or a cms with community features and drop our app into it.  It seems that most of these platforms seem to be organized around the idea that there is one network and everyone is part of that network, i.e. the [Facebook](http://www.facebook.com/) model.  A better model for our app is the [Ning](http://www.ning.com/) model.  We want a new sub-network for each of our customers, and different customers don't even need to know the others exist.  To further complicate things, we may at a later date want to allow very limited sharing between these sub networks.  Are there open source or commercial platforms that support creating many different subnetworks/communities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Groupsite is a commercial offering similar to Ning: http://www.groupsite.com/

Their features page (http://www.groupsite.com/features) makes a point to mention that they offer "Full-featured Subgroups: mini Groupsites within Groupsites".

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Wordpress mu (http://mu.wordpress.org/) for 'subnetworks' and maybe BuddyPress (http://buddypress.org/) for adding social networking features. Not ideal, but like you say most are based on the the 'Facebook' model such as Elgg (http://elgg.org/).

Comment: This looks promising.  I'll look into it.

Comment: It seems that in BuddyPress everything is just one monolithic network.  Thanks anyway.  It does look interesting.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider [DotNetNuke](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/). DotNetNuke has an open architecture and you can extend it by adding modules. It is open source and free, but you may need to buy a social module. One social module ([Smart-Thinker](http://www.smart-thinker.com/)) is free however. It supports creation of User Groups, which look very similar to what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at the [Jomsocial](http://www.jomsocial.com/) extension for [Joomla](http://www.joomla.org/). I haven't used it, but do use Joomla which I think is pretty good. It looks like a pretty extensive social networking extension and they have a [comparison chart](http://www.jomsocial.com/overview/comparison-chart.html) which includes Ning.

Also for Joomla is [Community Builder](http://www.joomlapolis.com/content/section/5/37/) which is a a free extension unlike Jomsocial.